# EF Core 2 duplicate column created with foreign key relationship

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-core-migrations

I'm trying add migration using EF core 2 code first method. The issue is that, the entities with foreign key relationship are created with a foreign key id suffixed with '1' at the end and a redundant column with the same name but without the 1 at the end which is not a foreign key.

Examples are my 2 classes, Store and StoreVisit as shown below:

**Store**

```
[Table("Store")]
public class Store
{
    public Store()
    {
        StoreVisits = new HashSet<StoreVisit>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int StoreId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)] 
    public string ShopName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ShopKeeper { get; set; } 

    public string ContactNo { get; set; }

    [StringLength(70)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)] 
    public string City { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<StoreVisit> StoreVisits { get; set; }
}
```

**Store Visit**

```
[Table("StoreVisit")]
public class StoreVisit
{

    [Key]
    public int StoreVisitId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public Store Store { get; set; }

}
```

The Visit class is created in the database with the column shown in the image below:

[image]

As you can see, the StoreVisit table has columns "StoreId1" which is the actual foreign key and "StoreId" which is not a foreign key.

I have even configured the relationship with Fluent API as below:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Store>()
            .HasMany(c => c.StoreVisits)
            .WithOne(e => e.Store)
            .IsRequired();
```

Can someone help.

Comment: Something is missing from the picture. Do you have `StoreId` property in your `StoreVisit` class? Or some fluent configuration not shown here?

Comment: Agreed. EF would not create the `StoreId` column on its own, because it's a `bigint` and the PK on `Store` is just `int`. Even if there was some issue with your entities/configuration that was causing EF to create the FK property twice, it would be two `int` columns. The fact that it's a `bigint` means you're adding that manually somewhere.

Comment: I had this issue. This was down to a glitch in the way I was doing the fluent API cascade delete restrictions. I set up a relationship with an incorrect HasForeignKey , and the end result was that EF started creating duplicate fields.

Answer (score 3):

**Note** that Entity Framework Core *is smart enough* to detect relationships among your classes which will be turned into database tables with relationships if you use its [conventions](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions). So **this is redundant** to use annotations like `[Key]` above `StoreId` property.

Second thing, **As an advice**, try to use simple and clean names for classes or properties as they can be potentially similar to those automatically created by EF. For example, in your case I prefer to avoid using `store` inside `StoreVisit` class name again (e.g in case of *many to many* relationship, derived table is named *StoreVisit* like one that you employed just without 's', *Although **your case is one to many***),

And **Final tip** is the reason for appearing redundant *StoreId* column. Actually, In your case, this is not necessary to use Fluent API as EF can detect the relationship. In addition, you've written wrong configuration for `modelBuilder`. **So remove it and let EF to generate it** (unless you plan to have *fully defined relationship* to consume its advantages in your code).

- The *StoreId* is one that you told EF to generate it (as `required`)
  in `modelBuilder`.
- The *StoreId1* is EF Auto generated column (Foreign Key) based on one
  to many relationship. '1' is appended in order to avoid column name duplication.

Comment: I see, I am having the same issue here. Firstly I am creating the navigational properties and respective foreign keys like: Catalog { int CatalogId; List<Item> items }; Item { int ItemId, int CatalogId, Catalog parentCatalog  }; With this configured relations are setup fine. Then I am adding the fluent API foreign key relationship for the same as I need Cascading delete behavior. My services rely upon CatalogId field in Item so I cannot remove it after configuring it with fluent api. Now EF Core2 generates the CatalogId and CatalogId1 FKs, both int's and second w/o Cascade. How to fight this?

Comment: I found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52957270 . Just use Entity.HasOne with lambda to specify exact element otherwise EF will create new one.

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key needs to be defined on the class.

```
[Table("StoreVisit")]
public class StoreVisit
{

    [Key]
    public int StoreVisitId { get; set; }

    public int StoreId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public Store Store { get; set; }

}
```

It also would hurt to add the foreign key reference to the Fluent API.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Store>()
            .HasMany(c => c.StoreVisits)
            .WithOne(e => e.Store)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.StoreId)
            .IsRequired();
```

Comment: The trick here is that the HasForeignKey in the question is missing.

Comment: I had HasForeignKey but it still ended up creating duplicate foreignKey